# How can hide Image control with expression in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, image

> My question is that i have a image in a image control HTML now i need to hide that image.
>     I have tried the code to hide the image as given below..

```
if ($("#ImageTest").attr(src="") == true) {
    $("#img").hide();
}
else {
    $("#img").show();
}

HTML code

<div id="ImageTest"> 
    <img id="img" src="C:\Image\MyImage\img.png"/> 
</div>
```

> it is working fine when i provide an id to image control "img".
>   but i need the code in which i am not providing the id to the image control. like    >given below

```
<div id="ImageTest"> 
    <img src="C:\Image\MyImage\img.png"/> 
</div>
```

> I need to search the control with expression like "src" and given image path, and after that i have to hide that image control.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select images with empty `src` value and hide them. The images that have source not equal to empty string will be visible by default. You probably need to give the `url` instead of giving physical path of image.

```
$('img[src=""]').hide()
```

Your current condition also seem incorrect.

*Change*

```
if ($("#ImageTest").attr(src="") == true) {
```

*To*

```
if ($("#ImageTest").attr() == "" {
```

Answer (score 1):

you can select using the `img` tag and check for `src` try this

```
$('img').each(function(){
if ($(this).attr("src") == "") {
    $("#img").hide();
}
else {
    $("#img").show();
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use such code:

```
$('img[src="C:\Image\MyImage\img.png"]').hide()
```